# How to redirect urls for the below pattern?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url pattern like below. I need to redirect for base url.

from http://www.example.com/https://www.othersite.com/watch?v=465sdfsf
to http://www.example.com

I tried 301 redirect But it fails.

So please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /www\.othersite\.com/watch\?v=465sdfsf [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry Its not working. So please explain it or find other solution

Comment: I also tried that one. but if page loads the url have https:// turns to https:/ and 404 page came.